# Simple script to convert Unicode

Tags: bash, unicode

I am looking for a simple script (preferably in bash) to convert to and from Unicode strings, such as:

```
<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U0062><U002D><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0020><U0025><U0054>
```

This is the format used, for example, in locale definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
STR=$(echo "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U0062><U002D><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0020><U0025><U0054>" | sed 's/<U/\\u/g; s/>//g')
printf $STR
```

if your printf does not support unicode on you shell/os, then try with python:

```
python -c 'print u"'$STR'"'
```

Comment: strange. This does not work either. I get just this same output: `\u0025\u0059\u002D\u0025\u0062\u002D\u0025\u0064\u0020\u0020\u0025\u0054`

Comment: what is your `type printf` output?

Comment: @user1968963 if shell buildin `printf` cannot handle unicode, you can try `/usr/bin/printf` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input *script* is in a file named `input`:

```
printf "$(sed 's/<U\(....\)>/\\u\1/g' input)"
```

The `sed` script is used to change all `<U0025>` in `\u0025` format. Then `printf` is used to interpret the `\u0025`.

Alternatively, if the input is not in a file:

```
printf "$(sed 's/<U\(....\)>/\\u\1/g' <<< $input)"
```

or:

```
printf "$(sed 's/<U\(....\)>/\\u\1/g' <<< "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U0062><U002D><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0020><U0025><U0054>")"
```

Comment: damm it, you ware first :-)
Anyhow, +1

Comment: I get this output: `\u0025\u0059\u002D\u0025\u0062\u002D\u0025\u0064\u0020\u0020\u0025\u0054`

Answer (score 1):

### Perl solution:

To utf8:

```
perl -pCO -e 's/<U(.*?)>/chr hex $1/eg'
```

Back:

```
perl -pCI -e 's/(.)/sprintf"<U%04X>",ord $1/ge'
```